# Removing Element with jQuery $(this) object not working

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to remove an object on my html page that is dynamically added in with jQuery and, of course, it is not removing the element. Below is a small snippet of the jQuery code and below that is the HTML I have. When I look at the console log the message is successfully printed but the object is still on the screen.Is there something I'm missing?

WHAT IS SUPPOSED TO HAPPEN:
When a user clicks on the `<h1>` element "MATH", a div with class "content" is supposed to appear underneath it. Then when that div element is clicked, the object should be removed.

jQuery Code:

```
 $(document).ready(function (){
        var subject = $('.subject');
        var content = "<ul style='list-style-type: none;'> <li>some text</li> </ul>";
        subject.click(function(){
            $(this).append('<div class="content">' + content + '</div>');
        });
        $(document).on('click','div.content', function(){
            console.log("no such luck");//this prints
            $(this).remove();//this does not remove element however
        });
    });
```

HTML Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
...

<body>
    <div class="jumbotron" style="background-color: lightblue; height: 25%;">
        <h1 class="subject" target="1">MATH</h1>
    </div>
 </body>
 </html>
```

I've used the above code before in a Codeacademy example and it worked fine.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It does remove the element, but the click propogates to the `.subject` event handler, which just inserts another element just like it.

As you need propagation to be able to delegate to the document, you could just make sure the `.subject` event handler doesn't insert more elements when it's not clicked directly

```
subject.click(function(e) {
    if ( e.target === this )
        $(this).append('<div class="content">' + content + '</div>');
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/7nyhoc2w/)

Comment: You're right that was my problem. What I ended up doing instead was i changed "append" to "after" and that solved my problem, thank you.

Comment: Moving the element outside the `.subject` will of course also work

Answer (score 0):

Contrary to adeneo's answer I had better luck with the following [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fq2qfu6j/#&togetherjs=61Vmw3eNiL)

```
$(document).on('click','div.content', function(){
        console.log("no such luck");//this prints
        console.log(JSON.stringify(this));
        $('div.content').remove();
});
```

The trick was to use remove() on 'div.content', not on 'this' - as seen in console log output, 'this' is an empty object when you define handler this way (or am I missing something here? I feel like there might be room for deeper understanding).

Comment: this is assuming that only one `div.content` exists in page, otherwise will remove all and not specific instance

Comment: `this` is not empty, but using `$('div.content')` also matches the new element that was inserted in the event handler for `.subject`, which is why both are removed, and any other elements matching that selector.

Comment: *"'this' is an empty object when you define handler this way"* - no, it is definitely the clicked element, and you can see that if you don't use `JSON.stringify` on it.

Answer (score 0):

This is a different approach in order to stop the event propagation:

```js
$(function () {
  var content = "<ul style='list-style-type: none;'> <li>some text</li> </ul>";
  $(document).on('click', '.subject', function(e) {
    $(this).append('<div class="content">' + content + '</div>');
  });
  $(document).on('click','div.content', function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
    $(this).remove();//this does not remove element however
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>

<div class="jumbotron" style="background-color: lightblue; height: 25%;">
  <h1 class="subject" target="1">MATH</h1>
</div>
```